# Unterschied zwischen einen Preis "einsetzen" und "ansetzen"

Tags: word-choice

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Formulierungen: einen Preis einsetzen und einen Preis ansetzen? Z.B.

> In den meisten Fällen sind 2 Preise eingesetzt, nämlich für 10 und 100
>   Gramm.
>
> Sein Unternehmen hat die Preise immer viel höher angesetzt als andere
>   Hersteller.

Beide Sätze bedeuten für mich, dass der Preis festgelegt wurde, oder liege ich hier falsch?

Comment: Einen Preis kann man i.A. nicht *einsetzen*, zumindestens nicht im Sinne von "ansetzen, festlegen"

Comment: @tofro: Es gibt Steckkarten, insbesondere bei Obst, Gemüse, Käse, Wurst und Fleisch, wo der Preis tatsächlich eingesetzt wird.

Comment: @userunknown das würde ich jetzt als *auszeichnen* bezeichnen

Comment: Man könnte den Preis als Parameter bei einer Berechnung o.ä. einsetzen. Ob das gemeint ist kann man nur aus dem Kontext herleiten.

Comment: @tofro: Auszeichnen ist es auch, wenn man mit einem Etikettenroller ein Papperl draufpappt.

Comment: Bevor ich die Frage genau gelesen hatte, dachte ich beim Einsatz eines Preises eher an eine Wettbewerbs Prämie: Aber da wäre doch auch "das Ansetzen einer Belohnung"  angebracht, oder?

Answer (score 5):

Ja, es gibt einen Unterschied:

Die Formulierung

> einen Preis *einsetzen*

ist unüblich und daher stilistisch schlecht. Man sollte diese Formulierung nicht verwenden. Was genau sie bedeuten soll, wenn man sie mal hört oder liest, muss man aus dem Kontext erschließen.

Einsetzen kann man unter anderem auch Dinge, die in bestimmte Aussparungen passen. Wenn diese Dinge kleine Täfelchen mit aufgedruckten Ziffern sind, und wenn sich die Aussparungen in Preisschildern befinden, dann kann man eben diese Ziffern in die Aussparungen des Preisschildes *einsetzen,* so dass dann diese Ziffern einen Preis anzeigen.

Dann kann man natürlich auch Personen in Ämter einsetzen, Fische in einem Teich einsetzen, man kann Werkzeuge einsetzen um ein Ziel zu erreichen, Regen kann plötzlich einsetzen, und Personen können sich für eine Sache einsetzen.

Aber Preise einzusetzen ist unüblich.

---

> Einen Preis *ansetzen*

bedeutet, dass man für eine Ware oder eine Dienstleistung *vorerst* einen Preis festlegt, der möglicherweise bald wieder verändert werden muss, oder vielleicht auch längerfristig in Verwendung bleibt. Beim Verb *ansetzen* klingt eine gewisse Unentschlossenheit mit.

Will man aussagen, dass man sich endgültig für einen Preis entschieden hat, ist diese Formulierung besser:

> Einen Preis *festlegen*

Comment: für mich sind zwar solche Fragen nicht out of topic, sie sind auch nicht irrelevant ... aber die Diskussionen darüber - was richtig  ist und was nicht - sind doch immer subjektiv und sophistisch, nachdem wir doch  wissen, dass die Regeln des Duden einfach dem Volksmund folgen. Wenn statistisch genug Leute etwas falsch schreiben, wird es als gültig betrachtet.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: Ich nehme an, du wolltest schreiben: *»Wenn statistisch genug Leute etwas **anders** schreiben, wird es als gültig betrachtet.«* Denn wenn es gültig ist, ist es ja nicht mehr falsch. Aber ja: Genau so funktioniert jede lebende Sprache. Aber die Tatsache, dass eine Sprache lebt und sich ständig in einem Zustand des Wandels befindet, verbietet nicht, trotzdem danach zu fragen was richtig und was falsch ist. Daher sind solche Fragen durchaus relevant. Anderenfalls könnte man ja gleich postulieren, es gäbe keinen Unterschied zwischen richtig und falsch.

Comment: Nein, selbst wenn etwas gültig ist, kann  es immer noch falsch sein. Nimm die Trennungsregeln, die Komma Regeln, da gibt es vielen Unsinn, den die neue Rechtschreibung des Duden zu gelassen hat, obwohl viele Schriftsteller und Germanisten dagegen protestiert haben. Mit dem Rest deiner Aussage betreffend des Wandels einer Sprache bin ich 100% einverstanden.